# React/Axios receive response status and JSON like Postman

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, postman

My endpoint will send a response like this:

```
res.status(400).json({"note","this email is already taken"});
```

With React I am using axios as follows

```
export const signUpUser = (email, password) => {
   const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
   };

   return axios
      .post(
         https://domain.something + "/signup",
         { email, password },
         { headers ,}
      )
      .then((res) => {
         return res;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
         return err;
      });
};
```

postman can parse it as follows:
[image]

however I can not extract the JSON with react this is what displays console log shows:

[image]

Comment: Which is the react code which creates de request? The problem seems to be that the response is throwing an exception as it's a 400 code, you should hadle those exceptions whith a 'catch'

Comment: Also it's `json({note:"this email is already taken"})`

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? React doesn't come with a data access library.

Comment: I am using axios in this case

Comment: @prabhu correct the code is written as you put it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading I learned that Axios processes express responses differently than other libraries.  It treats the response as an object and only appears to take the first one (chaining did not work).

solution:

```
            return res.json({
               message: "This email is currently in use.",
               status: 400,
               foo: "bar",
               data: "this is the data",
            })
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default 400 is the code for bad request, have a try to change the code to 200 or 2xx.

Comment: I am aware of that but Postman can parse the 400 code and deliver the `.json`  that is really what my question is.